# “In custody of the” vs. “in the custody of the”

Tags: definite-article, determiners

> - The castle is now in **the** custody of the state.

What would change if I omit the article “the” from the sentence?

to be like:

> - The castle is now in custody of the state.

Comment: The collection of art books is now in **the** custody of the university.

Comment: Is it grammatically correct to omit “the” from the sentence, and would the meaning change? @MvLog

Comment: I think it would be incorrect to leave out **the** since **custody** without **the** usually refers to a) the right to take care of a child (_He got custody of his son after the divorce_) or b) when someone is kept in prison (_A man is being held in police custody in connection with the murder._)

Comment: **in (the) custody of ...** --either way is fine. No practical difference in meaning.

Comment: I would not use "custody" about something immovable like a castle. I would also not use "in custody of" without an article, though I would use "in custody" without either article or prepositional complement.

Comment: in custody of his {family member} is very common.

Comment: @ColinFine  checking Ngram, expressions like "take custody of the property" or "take custody of the records" are not uncommon.  *Custody* goes with *custodian*, a person charged with taking care of something, be it a child, a house, or a sum of money.  That being said, traditionally the person charged with taking care of a *castle* (in the lord's absence) is called a **steward**, although that might not apply here.

Comment: A search in GloWbE shows 5231 hits for "in custody", of which only 190 are "in custody of"; but 905 hits for "in the custody of". "In custody of" shows more hits for india and Nigeria than for UK or US (the numbers are quite small, though).

Comment: @Andrew. Interesting. GloWbE has only two instances of "custody of the property" (from Bangla Desh and Kenya), one for "custody of the house" (in that sense - from the US), one for "custody of the structure" (from Bangla Desh) and none at all for "custody of the building". It's hard to do a more general search, because many examples are the opposite meaning (custody of the [authority]).